# Send XML to WebService

Tags: apache-flex, web-services

I have an application in Flex how create and XML in UTF-8. When I open it everything is ok.
I send it to a server using a webservice (the xml is send like a string), the server receive the xml but all the accent, degree symbol and some other stuff are gone.

I create an XML and save it in a file

```
var xml:XML = myObject.xml;
file = new File(myObject.path);
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fileStream.writeUTFBytes("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" + xml);
fileStream.close();
```

Later I reopened it and send it

```
var file:File = new File(myObject.path);
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
var xmlText:String = fileStream.readUTFBytes(fileStream.bytesAvailable);
var call:Object = service.AirSave("username", "password", xmlText);
call.addResponder(responder);
```

And a part of my XML

```
<Gen Name="App1">
  <Fam Name="Date">
    <Peo>
      <First>René</First>
      <Last>Jean</Last>
    </Peo>
    <Peo>
      <First>François</First>
      <Last>Jean</Last>
    </Peo>
  </Fam>
</Gen>
```

Someone know why and how to fix it?
Thank you

Comment: How are you creating the string? can you show the code & xml.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're saving it to disk in the first place, but it seems to me that you're losing your information somewhere.  I would check every string in debug to see where you've lost the characters. How are you sending it over to the server (ie. what's 'service')?

Comment: Can you verify that it is saved correctly at least?  This will tell us if the error is on the save or serve side.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I find the problem.

The server save the content of the file in a database but SQL Server don't support UTF-8. So bye bye accent.